# Why does SonarQube reopen issues marked as False Positive?

Tags: sonarqube

Our organization is just starting to use SonarQube and we are seeing something that seems strange to us.  We have the plugin that allows users to mark an issue as "False Positive" but any issues that we mark as "False Positive" have their status reset to "Open" the next time SonarQube runs.  The same thing happens for issues marked as "Won't Fix"- they are reopened on the next SonarQube run.

Is there any way to mark an issue as something that you will never fix so that you don't see it again after subsequent runs?

Comment: If they are really the same issues, you should see the various status changes in the issue's history. If you don't, then it's not the same issue or at least its not recognized as so. Might be a bug, might be not. You don't even provide the version of SQ you are using in your question, there is no way to tell if that's a known problem or not.