# Sonarqube 5.6.3 reopens issue marked as won't fix

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.6

we are using SonarQube version **5.6.3** and it is installed on linux server(
**CentOS release 6.8** ). Even after marking issue as "Won't Fix" manually, the issue seems to get open after another analysis in jenkins ( **Jenkins ver. 1.642.3**) . Out of many engagements (appprox. 100+), One engagement holds its project snapshot from August 2015 to till date. I was thinking of deleting the snapshot, but engagement wants an another alternative. I am not sure what is causing this issue. Does anyone has the idea about this issue? I have referred [Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38794909/why-does-sonarqube-reopen-issues-marked-as-wont-fix) and 
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32364203/why-does-sonarqube-reopen-issues-marked-as-false-positive#), but it didnt had any answer. Does anyone has any idea about it?

Comment: can anyone update us regarding this question.? is this a bug in Sonarqube? as we are getting the same issue in version 6.2 as well.